# Loop in R: how to store the output?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

i'm really new to R..and i'm trying to save the output of print(w1) into a matrix (1001x4) (or even in a matrix 4004x1) of the following loop but for me it is impossible. I tried to save w1 into a matrix after print(w1)`b[,i]<-1/n^2*(sum1+n+sum2)` , but it saves only the last 4 outputs. My code is:

```
n=4
for(a in seq(0,1,0.001)){
for(i in 1:n){
sum1<-0
sum2<-0
for(j in 1:n){
  if(j>i){
    sum1<-sum1+(n/j)^a
  }
  else if(j<i){

    sum2<-sum2-(n/i)^a 


  }

} 

w1<-1/n^2*(sum1+n+sum2)

print(w1)
#b[,i]<-1/n^2*(sum1+n+sum2)
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help! Anastasia.

Comment: If you don't use an index on the LHS of an assignment inside all your for loops you will be overwriting those values every time through the loop. This seems to be a very common error among persons new to R, probably because the SAS and SPSS languages have implicit row indexing and people don't understand that fact when they move to other languages. I doubt that persons coming from "real" programming languages face the same cognitive hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only stores the last 4 outputs because you are using `i` as index (which will only be 1 to 4).

If you want to store all the values you will have to append new values to the current vector. You can do so like this:

```
vec <- c() # Create a new empty vector before the loop
# After print(w1) add
vec <- c(vec, w1) # This will append the new value (w1) to the vector
```